# How to convert netbeans jar file to an executable file that can run the program without the need to install JRE?

Tags: netbeans

I have created a program in Apache Netbeans, and I have to pass it to my professor. But my professor wants us to pass an executable file that no longer needs to install Netbeans and Java Runtime Environment. how do I do that? I have already converted a .exe file of my program but when my professor tried to open it does nothing. The exec file won't even run. How do I fix this tho? Ty!

Comment: I'd use launch4j  and bundle the jre with it: http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/ You can set it up through an ant task if you want some automation.

Comment: hi, i've tried to use that already and I have successfully converted my jar file to an exec file using launch4j application, however when I tried to run and click on my exec file, nothing happens and it won't even run. Why is that so? I have tried other netbeans project and it worked, but there is one specific project that doesnt pls help

Comment: Here is the specific file I am talking about. The jar file is located in the dist folder. Hope you can try it out and share some thoughts pls. 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sgNJ9N4Vd65i6xgjjod2MfDcInfXOLrF/view